# Installation issue with Trac Project

Tags: python, trac

I ran into an issue running Trac with Docker using this Docker file:  https://github.com/walty8/docker-trac-dev.

The error that I am seeing is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/trac-trunk/trac/web/api.py", line 708, in send_error
    data, 'text/html')
    File "/root/trac-trunk/trac/web/chrome.py", line 1095, in render_template
    if self.stream_filters:
    File "/root/trac-trunk/trac/core.py", line 82, in extensions
    components = [component.compmgr[cls] for cls in classes]
    File "/root/trac-trunk/trac/core.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    component = cls(self)
    File "/root/trac-trunk/trac/core.py", line 144, in __call__
    self.__init__()
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tracdeveloper/log.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.log_handler.setFormatter(self.log._trac_handler.formatter)
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute '_trac_handler'
```

I am running this on Ubuntu 16.04.01. I have tried the installation with older versions of trac to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution..

The Dockerfile is missing a crucial package; TracDeveloper.
Adding the following line to the Dockerfile should fix this issue.

```
RUN pip install tracdeveloper
```